# Rails has_many STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many, single-table-inheritance, sti

I've trying to implement a STI on rails 4, but I can't make it work, I've search a lot of results but none worked. Here is the problem:

I have an instance class, using STI I have a subclass Car (a dummy subclass) and ScheduledInstance class.

```
class Instance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
end 
class Car < Instance end 
class ScheduledInstance < Instance end 

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :instances,          dependent:  :destroy
  has_many :cars
  has_many :scheduledinstances
end
```

When trying to get a task's cars or a task's scheduledinstances, it doesn't work.(I have a type column on Instance table)

```
Task.first.cars
  Task Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks"  ORDER BY "tasks"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NameError: uninitialized constant Task::Car
```

however, if I do Task.first.instances, and then Task.first.cars, it works ok. What I am missing?.

Also based on your answer, what changes do I need to apply to make it work with a has_many through?

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :tasks,      dependent: :destroy
  has_many :instances,  through: :tasks
end
```

Comment: I had to vote up just for the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking the error may be due to file naming. Could you confirm that you have:

```
# models/car.rb
class Car < Instance
end 

# models/scheduled_instance.rb
class ScheduledInstance < Instance
end
```

Then in your task.rb, you should have:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :instances,          dependent:  :destroy
  has_many :cars
  has_many :scheduled_instances
end
```

Comment: it worked!. I thought I could have them in the same file. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of suggestions:

Have you tried adding `belongs_to :task` to the `Car` and `ScheduledInstance` Models? This may require that you also add references to the DB.

```
$ rails g migration add_task_id_to_car task:references
$ rake db:migrate
```

OR

Have you tried joining on the query?

```
@task = Task.joins(:instances, :cars, :scheducled_instances).first
```

Comment: adding belongs_to :task to the Car model doesn't work. Didn't it already have it (through the inheritance)?.
The second idea gives me this:
    NameError: uninitialized constant Task::Scheduledinstance

Comment: What about just `Task.joins(:instances).first.cars` ?